# Sort the $results array from the afterFind callback by calculated field?

Tags: cakephp, sorting, cakephp-2.0

First posted question, I have a little bit of Cake experience, but I am far from being proficient. In my Model - Product, I use the afterFind callback to do some calculations. 
Firstly, it checks if the warranty of a product is still active (startDate + warranty_period), then it calculates how much time is left on the warranty. 
To do that, I use:

```
$future = '+'.$results[$key]['Product']['warranty_period'].'months';    
$startDate = $results[$key]['Product']['created'];
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($future, strtotime($startDate)));
$curDate = date('Y-m-d');

if($endDate > $curDate){
$date1 = new DateTime($endDate);
$date2 = new DateTime($curDate);
$interval = $date1 -> diff($date2);
```

By default, $interval gets returned as a string of numbers, such as '01119'.
I then run through the following code to output it as such: 0 years, 11 months, 19 days.

```
//years     
if($interval->y > 0){
$years = $interval->y.' years, ';
}
//months        
if($interval->m > 0){
$months = $interval->m.' months, ';
}
//days
if($interval->d > 0){
$days = $interval->d.' days';
}
$results[$key]['Product']['warranty_time'] = $years.$months.$days;
}else{
$results[$key]['Product']['warranty_time'] = 'Expired';
}
```

The results of these calculations are then passed in the $results array returned from the afterFind.
Here is my actual question: How would I go about sorting the $results array according to the warranty_time left?

I use Paginator on some of my other fields, with echo $this->Paginator->sort('name', Name);
This works very nicely to sort the records ASC or DESC fairly quickly, but I cannot get it to work with my warranty_time field. I suspect that might be because cake sees the $interval as a String, not an int or other numeric data type.

I thought seeing as though $interval gets returned as a 'number', such as '01119' would it be possible to sort the array according to that and then do the formatting in the view? What would be the best approach for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the easiest way to do this might be in the database - something like this:

```
$data = $this->MyModel->find('all', array('order' => 
    array('end_date - start_date' => 'DESC')));
```

Obviously that's not the right calculation for you, but you should be able to do it using things like MySQL's DATE_ADD to work out the warranty end date etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it so that the calculations are done before adding the new record to the table, so that the values are actually saved into the db, that way I can run a normal SQL ORDER, as well as other useful things, like finding products that expire between certain dates etc. Your answer didn't help me at first, but after a lot of researching, I found that sorting by calculated field in general can become a bit of a problem when thousands of records are being called, This led me to do things the other way around. Once agian thank you kind sir.

Comment: No problem, glad it (indirectly) helped!